# Copy real time data from Azure SQL into Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-data-warehouse

I would like to copy our data from Azure SQL (OLTP) into Azure Datawarehouse. I want the path to be close to real time.

The Microsoft system looks it takes two steps copying data from SQL Server into Azure Data Warehouse.

- First into Blob Storage with Azure Data Factory
- and then with Polybase into Azure Datawarehouse.

It looks like a two step ETL and not close to real time.

Does Microsoft have any simpler way of copying data from Azure SQL into DW for analytics?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using [Striim](https://www.striim.com/azure-sql-data-warehouse/) as mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-real-time-data-warehousing-with-azure-sql-data-warehouse/) by Microsoft Program Manager of Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Ellis Butterfield.